# C# - Como adicionar resultados de um SELECT em uma List e usar a list para Popular uma Table

Tags: c#, table, lista

Tudo certo?
Eu sou novo em C# e estou estagnado em um probleminha com um projeto no Visual Studio:

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com padrão DAO (DATA ACCESS OBJETC). Tenho uma interface responsável pelos métodos que irão realizar a persistência chamada InterfaceDAOCurso:

```
public interface InterfaceDAOCurso{
    void adicionarCurso(Curso c);
    List<Materia> pesquisarCurso(String curso);
}
```

E a classe que implementa essa interface DAOCurso:

```
public class DAOCurso : InterfaceDAOCurso{

public static String stringConexao = "Data Source=LOCAL-pc ;" +
                             "Initial Catalog=tccDataBase;" +
                             "Trusted_Connection=yes";

public DAOCurso()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}

public void adicionarCurso(Curso c)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = stringConexao;
    String sql = "Insert into curso (id,nomeCurso,turno,sigla) values(" + c.getId() + ",'" + c.getNomeCurso() + "','" + c.getTurnoCurso() + "','" + c.getSigla() + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Eu gostaria de implementar o método do tipo List retornando uma lista com a quantidade de matérias referentes a esse curso. Entretanto, estou com problemas na hora de popular a lista com resultado da Query. (O problema não é o comando sql). É possível usar result set? Como se daria a implementação dessa função?

Outra coisa que ainda não me é muito claro é o funcionamento da Table no asp e como eu poderia popular essa table com a lista que será retornada da minha função.

Desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: Não sei se entendi completamente a pergunta , você quer popular uma list com o resultado do comando ?

Comment: Eu posso ter complicado um pouco rs. Eu quero popular uma List com os resultados de um Select. E depois utilizar a lista populada para preencher uma tabela com os dados resultantes desse select. Deu pra entender?
Em java eu utilizava o resultSet mas não consegui uma solução semelhante em C#. Eu estou programando pra web e Poderia ser Table, gridView ou qualquer componente do tipo para passar os resultados da pesquisa.

Comment: Vitor da uma olhada na resposta que postei acredito que este exemplo irá te ajudar , me desculpe pela demora .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este e um exemplo de um `método` que retorna uma lista do tipo `string`.

Neste caso estou usando um banco de dados `Firebird`.

```
 public static List<string> Listar(string curso)
        {
            try
            {
                //Variavel local
                FbCommand command;
                FbDataAdapter dataAdapter;

                //Aqui você abre a conexão com o banco

                //Consulta
                command = new FbCommand(@"
                SELECT 
                NOME
                FROM  CURSO", ( sua conexão) ;

                //Intermediario recebe a respota do comandos sql enviado  
                dataAdapter = new FbDataAdapter(command);

                //Estrutura da tabela 
                DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();

                //Preencher com a estrutura do select enviado com as tuplas
                dataAdapter.Fill(objDataTable);

                //Cria lista
                List<string> ListaDeDados = new List<string>();

                //Percorrer as linhas do datatable para adicionar na lista 
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in objDataTable.Rows)
                {
                    //Adiciona na lista Especificando a clouna 
                    string informação = dataRow["NOME"].ToString();
                    ListaDeDados.Add(informação);
                }

                return ListaDeDados;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Trata exceção
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                //Fechar Conexão 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sua resposta me deu um norte. Pesquisei bastante alguns métodos e funções do próprio Asp pra tentar realizar e Resolvi utilizar uma GridView como na minha resposta abaixo: